# What is Adobe Air Packager for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, flash, actionscript-3, air

I just read this annoucement about Apple lifting restrictions on its third-party developer guidelines with direct implications for [Adobe’s Packager for iPhone](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/).

[http://blogs.adobe.com/conversations/2010/09/great-news-for-developers.html](http://blogs.adobe.com/conversations/2010/09/great-news-for-developers.html--)

- I just want to know what kind of applications can be built using this packager?
- Can I build applications using Flex/Actionscript and convert to iphone apps using this packager?
- What effect do you think it might have on programming apps using Objective-C?

Comment: You should create a separate question and ask the non argumentative parts of this question. What can you build (might be too general, maybe refine the question a little), can you use Flex/Actionscript, are valid questions for Stack Overflow, but asking what effect this will have on ObjC is not.

Comment: @Jasarien - Thanks. Didn't get too may answers, will see if I get more by following your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your points seem to ask for opinions but most of your questions would best be served with their FAQ. http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Packager_for_iPhone:Developer_FAQ
IMHO for this one

```
What effect do you think it might have on programming apps using Objective-C?
```

Fewer people will attempt to learn Objective-C and may also not start using Xcode.

**Update 10/24/2011**

It would seem that adobe moved the link, so here are some others to get you going:
http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/09/packager-for-iphone-refresher.html

Developing for ipad
http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplatform/2010/01/building_ipad_apps.html

Developing for iOS using Flash Professional
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html

How to use Adobe's iPhone Packager without an Apple Developer Subscription
http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-Adobes-iPhone-Packager-without-an-Appl/